# Add a class depending on leaflet js zoom level

Tags: javascript, leaflet

Been having an issue with one of my maps that uses leaflet.js.

I have some elements that are present on the map at a zoom level of 6 and higher (as a reference, 1 is world view - so the higher the number the more granular the view).

I need to add a class when the map is at a zoom level greater than 6 to a class to ensure it doesn't appear on the map. I would need to ensure the function is continually loaded every time there is a change. I think this is an event listener?

Trouble is I am not terribly good with javascript and I am struggling to pull the information I need through. I have hit some roadblocks lately and my confidence is knocked.

I have some pseudo code I have written.

```
    function myFunction() {
if zoom > 4 {
    element.classList.add("disappear");
}
};

var element = document.getElementById("dma-marker-icon leaflet-marker-icon leaflet-zoom-animated leaflet-clickable");
myFunction() // Call listener function at run time
addListener(myFunction) // Attach listener function on state changes
```

Could you please help me refine this? Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1):

There's an event on a leaflet map which fires after the map zoom has changed - `zoomend`. So if you listen for that event, you can add or remove the class on your target element accordingly. You don't show much of your code so the variable names here will probably not match yours, but ...

```
myMap.on('zoomend', myFunction);

function myFunction(e) {
   if myMap.getZoom() > 4 {
    element.classList.add("disappear");    
 }
 else {
    element.classList.remove("disappear");
 }
}
```